# Converting design from tables to divs?

Tags: php, html, css

OpenSource project at sourceforge.net/projects/totalshopuk/files/

The project currently uses Tables for design and I'm slowing converting everything to DIVs.

Table Demo http://www.totalshopuk.com/

My progress so far can be found at http://ci2.totalshopuk.com/
as you can see (when zoomed in and measured) it doesn't quite line up.

Would anyone be able to help line up the DIVs correctly and to get the border on the right to flow to the bottom without specifying a fixed height?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Why not specify the border on the outer `wrapper` div if you want it to go all the way to the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can offer some advice when you're venturing into the amazing world of tableless web design (congratz on that, by the way).

Do yourself a favor and use a CSS Grid. It'll solve many of your problems with alignments and distribution of elements on the page.

From what I could see, you're using just your own CSS to do everything.

Take a look at [960](http://960.gs/) and [CSSGrid](http://cssgrid.net/) (I really love this last one), and see if using that makes your life easier.

Comment: I had a look at 960 before but didn't understand it originally. Just revisted the site and figured it out. That is perfect thanks very much, should have a DIVs designed site in no time :-)

Comment: Glad it helped! You can accept the answer if you believe it solves your problem :)